# I am trying to input sentences in string arrays and display them in reverse order

Tags: java

So far I have set it up so that the user can enter the number of sentences and input into each position of the String array using a for loop.

```
public class Test5 {
    public static String inputline;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of lines:");
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number=kb.nextInt();
        String []line=new String[number];
        for(int i=0;i<line.length+1;i++){
            line[i]=kb.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost your code is going to read in 1 more time than you want which will cause an array out of bounds exception. Next you will want to do nextLine() to account for the new line character being entered by the user. Try this:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of lines:");
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
int number=Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
String []line=new String[number];
//loop through only the size of the array
for(int i=0; i < line.length; i++){
    line[i]=kb.nextLine();
}
//now to output the array in reverse order you need to start from the
//other end of the array
for(int i = line.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.println(line[i]);
}
//always close the Scanner when done
kb.close();
```

Some useful resources about Scanners - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I cant input sentences in the input array strings. when I do it does this
         Enter the number of lines:3
         this is line 1
         line
         is
         this

Comment: when you grab user input typically you try to grab lines at a time so thats why i use nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: The problem I am having when using 'nextLine()' with that is that it is skipping array position 0

Comment: I ran this code and it does what you are asking... not sure why yours isn't working, did you try my sample code verbatim?

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity why did you use parse int in the input variable "number"?

Comment: So there are a couple of ways to go about doing it, i chose that method cause it's quick, but you get call getInt() then right after that call kb.nextLine() to grab that end of line character and sort of clear it out. give it a try